# how can I extract substring text in a response dataset using a regex in Lucee 5.x?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I'm rewriting a PHP web page into Lucee.

Original PHP Code:

```
while ( !feof ($fp) ) {

    $line = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        # Look for features in the output. You will see stuff like
        # Users of Allegro_Viewer: (Total of 5 licenses available
        if ( preg_match('/(Users of) (.*)(\(Total of) (\d+) (.*) (Total of) (\d+) /i', $line, $out) && !eregi("No such feature exists", $line) ) {
            $i++;
            $license_array[$i]["feature"] = $out[2];
            $license_array[$i]["num_licenses"] = $out[4];
            $license_array[$i]["licenses_used"] = $out[7];
        }
}
```

I'm looking to loop over this response text:

`lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2019 Flexera. All Rights Reserved. Flexible License Manager status on Sat 10/15/2022 11:19 [Detecting lmgrd processes...] License server status: 27002@someservername License file(s) on someservername: C:\SIMULIA\License\2022.HF2\win_b64\code\bin\simulialm.lic: someservername: license server UP (MASTER) v11.16.5 Vendor daemon status (on someservername): ABAQUSLM: UP v11.16.5 Feature usage info: Users of pydriver: (Total of 2 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cae: (Total of 2 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of abaqus: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of ams: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of aqua: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cosim_acusolve: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use);`

so that I can pull out the `Users of...` into an array (example shown below).

Users of pydriver: (Total of 2 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use)
Users of cae: (Total of 2 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use)
Users of abaqus: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use)
Users of ams: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use)
Users of aqua: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use)
Users of cosim_acusolve: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use)

I'm using the existing regex (which works under PHP) but not sure if it's right for the format my data is coming in under Lucee compared to how the original PHP code received it's response. For example, I *think* in PHP, the text is broken up by line whereas in Lucee, it's one long text string without carriage returns.

My regx is `'\/(Users of) (.*)(\(Total of) (\d+) (.*) (Total of) (\d+) \/i'` but I'm not clear on how to use it to pull out the data I need. I've tried cfloop, refindnocase, and reMatchNoCase but without success.

- my cfloop attempts dumps the whole data set into a single array
- my refindnocase returns 0.
- my reMatchNoCase (I think this is going to be the right function and that the issue may be with my regex given the format of my returned data)
- my regex validator can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/dDwvt4/1

**Ultimately I asking for help this PHP code block but I'd like to understand how to use regex to extra the data Lucee 5.x?**

**CODE I'VE TRIED**

`lmutil_response = 'lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2019 Flexera. All Rights Reserved. Flexible License Manager status on Sat 10/15/2022 11:19 [Detecting lmgrd processes...] License server status: 27002@someservername License file(s) on someservername: C:\SIMULIA\License\2022.HF2\win_b64\code\bin\simulialm.lic: someservername: license server UP (MASTER) v11.16.5 Vendor daemon status (on someservername): ABAQUSLM: UP v11.16.5 Feature usage info: Users of pydriver: (Total of 2 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cae: (Total of 2 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of abaqus: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of ams: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of aqua: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cosim_acusolve: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cosim_direct: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cse: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of design: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of euler_lagrange: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of gpgpu: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of multiphysics: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of parallel: (Total of 16384 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cfd: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of explicit: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of foundation: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of standard: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cse_token: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use)';`

Attempt A

```
local.data.regx = '/(Users of) (.*)(\(Total of) (\d+) (.*) (Total of) (\d+) /i';
myArray = listToArray(local.data.qryLicenseServerStatusByServerIDAndPort.lmutil_response,local.data.regx,false,true);
dump(myArray);
```

Attempt B

```
local.data.regx = '/(Users of) (.*)(\(Total of) (\d+) (.*) (Total of) (\d+) /i';
x = reMatchNoCase(local.data.regx, local.data.qryLicenseServerStatusByServerIDAndPort.lmutil_response)
dump(x);
```

Comment: Are there any line breaks in the response text?

Comment: Not in what I am seeing, no.

Comment: Deeper investigation shows the data may actually have lines breaks and that cf may be stripping out the line breaks. Not sure if that makes things easier or harder. :/

Comment: Your regex example at regex101.com isn't marching anything.

Comment: @AndreasRu - correct, I mention that above. The regex works under PHP but not under CF/Lucee. I'm not clear on where the issue lies, with the source data, the regex, or with the method in which I'm using the match the data.

Comment: @AndreasRu - I'll add that **if** the source data does actually have carriage returns in the data and cf is simply dropping them, the the regex does match up.  https://regex101.com/r/OXX24w/1

Comment: Do you mean CF is dropping them, or you're looking at the value in a web browser where LF characters have no meaning? Because those are two different things, and I think the latter is more likely.

Comment: What have you *tried* with CFML so far? Make sure to include that code in your question too. In fact... ditch the PHP stuff, that's largely irrelevant to the question at hand, which is "how to extract the substrings" _in CFML_. Can you also format the sample data so it's clear where the LFs are.

Comment: @AdamCameron - You are correct, the latter is more likely, I'm looking at them in Developer Tools. If I run the script locally that is being run by the server, it's simply a text file.

Comment: @AdamCameron I included the reference to the PHP to help illustrate what I'm trying to replicate (works in php) in case my approach is all wrong. If you still think I should remove it, I will.

Comment: I'll update the question with what I've tried if I can recreate it easy enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yer on the right track with `reMatchNoCase`. although probably no need for the `NoCase` bit.

Yer regex pattern seems overly complicated to me, and I *think* [this](https://trycf.com/gist/ed59b3d4f42f6356540d60de1b75cd74/lucee5?theme=monokai) is all you need:

```
s = "lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2019 Flexera. All Rights Reserved. Flexible License Manager status on Sat 10/15/2022 11:19 [Detecting lmgrd processes...] License server status: 27002@someservername License file(s) on someservername: C:\SIMULIA\License\2022.HF2\win_b64\code\bin\simulialm.lic: someservername: license server UP (MASTER) v11.16.5 Vendor daemon status (on someservername): ABAQUSLM: UP v11.16.5 Feature usage info: Users of pydriver: (Total of 2 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cae: (Total of 2 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of abaqus: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of ams: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of aqua: (Total of 41 licenses issued; Total of 0 licenses in use) Users of cosim_acusolve: (Total of 1 license issued; Total of 0 licenses in use);"

matches = s.reMatch("(Users of[^)]+\))")

writeDump(matches)
```

[image]

If there's a LF between each match, that'd be better to match on than the `)`, that said.

---

One other thing to note here, you are using PHP-format pattern delimiters (`/`), which isn't a thing in CFML. A pattern is just a string. These docs are a bit of a mess, and are for ColdFusion and not Lucee, but it should be the same on Lucee: [ColdFusion: Regular expression syntax](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-regular-expressions-in-functions/regular-expression-syntax.html).

Also I write extensively on all the ins and outs of CFML Regexes on my blog (this lot is from years ago, but should still be largely correct): [Regular expressions in CFML (part 8: the rest of CFML's support for regular expressions)](https://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/01/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part_17.html) (includes links back to previous 7 parts too.

Comment: Success!
I believe you may be correct o the `noCase` bit. I looked at simplifying the regex to build it back up but I still wasn't getting a match so. Now that I know this is possible, I may go back and try to figure out why my simplyer regex didn't work which is why I was focusing so much on the php variant because I _assumed_ it would work here.

Comment: I do not have to work with regex but once every so often but I'll check out the blog post you referenced. Thank you!